# JSLint out of scope when using a var inside the same var

Tags: javascript, jslint

**Update:** 
the user.forceLogout() is inside another http request funtion.

I get the following message when using JSLint:

'user' is out of scope. 
user.forceLogout(); // line...

My code is like:

```
var user = {
    logout: function () {
        var req = ... 
        $http(req).then(function (response) {
            user.forceLogout();
        });
    },
    forceLogout () {
       // code to force logout
    }
}
```

What should be the correct way to implement such code?

Comment: Well your code is invalid since you have a `.` instead of a `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Lints

Sam's pretty close. Here's a twist on the current constructor pattern favored (or at least accepted) by [the current version of JSLint](http://jslint.com).

```
/*jslint node, white */
var $http = require('https');

var user = (function() {
    "use strict";
    var userToReturn = {};

    userToReturn.forceLogout = function () {
        $http.someAction();      // kludge to keep from "empty block"
    };

    userToReturn.logout = function () {
        var req = {};            // just to push some code in to lint.
        $http(req).then(function (ignore) {
            userToReturn.forceLogout();
        });
    };

    return userToReturn;        // nicely protected object in closure.
}()); // immediate invocation gives you that `userToReturn` within closure.

user.logout(); // inserting to dodge "Unused 'user'." error
```

You could also create a factory pattern with a non-anonymous function if you wanted to create many of these.

#### Better

Now I think this workaround is a missed case by JSLint, as you've still called a function attached to an object while you're defining the object, and I bet what JSLint really prefers you do is this:

```
/*jslint node, white */
var $http = require('https');

var user = (function() {
    "use strict";
    var userToReturn = {};

    // private function for shared logic.
    function _forceLogout() {
        $http.someAction();     // kludge to keep from "empty block"
    }

    userToReturn.forceLogout = _forceLogout;

    userToReturn.logout = function () {
        var req = {};           // just to push some code in to lint.
        $http(req).then(function (ignore) {
            _forceLogout();
        });
    };

    return userToReturn;
}());

user.logout(); // inserting to dodge "Unused 'user'." error
```

Create a closure, factor out repeated code, then call it as a private method within that closure.

---

**NOTE:** Older versions of JSLint might complain about the param called `ignore`. You can just `(/*response*/)` if you don't want to take it all the way out. If your code really uses `response` later in that function, just leave it in, natch!

Apologies if you're not setting `$http` to `require('http')`. Change to whatever's appropriate, natch.

Anyhow, both lint as is.

Answer (score 1):

use 'this' instead of variable name inside the declaration/definition:

```
var user = {
    logout: function () {
        this.forceLogout();
    },
    forceLogout () {
        // code to force logout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to reference your user using `this` like:

```
var user = {
    logout: function () {
        this.forceLogout();
    },
    forceLogout () {
       // code to force logout
    }
}
```

You might want to read up on `this` on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Just fyi -- Note that [recent versions of JSLint](http://jslint.com/) no longer allow `this` by default, and would give an "Unexpected 'this'." error.

Comment: What? Well, good that most of the JavaScript ecosystem switched to jslint and eslint then...

Comment: js**h**int, I believe you mean. ;) Maybe it's good. But if I could get back all the time I wasted debugging code and "coaching up" people who didn't quite get `this`, closures, and contexts, I've have tens of thousands of dollars of time... /sigh [From Crockford](http://jslint.com/help.html), "*Having `this` in the language makes it harder to talk about the language. It is like pair programming with Abbott and Costello.*" There is a `this` directive in JSLint, however, if you still want to use `it`. I mean `this`. I don't know. <waits expectantly>

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses user before is is defined (in the definition).
You can define it like this, instead:

```
var user = {};
user.forceLogout = function(){};
user.logout = function(){ forceLogout(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor function:

```
var user = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.logout = function () {
        self.forceLogout();
    };

    self.forceLogout = function () {
       // code to force logout
    };
}
```

Using the `this` keyword inside a function will work most of the time but can do [weird things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) sometimes, that's why I assign it to `self` in the beginning of the constructor function `user`.

Then you create your user like this :

```
var myUser = new user();
```

The `new` keyword will create a new object and bind it to the `this` binding of your `user` constructor function, then it will return that new constructed object into `myUser`.